# Extracting the value of the local truncation error (LTE) at each integration step when using the ode() function from the deSolve R-package

Tags: r, ode, numerical-integration, lte

The default numerical scheme used by the ode() function in the deSolve R package is the lsode method which implements the BDF and implicit Adams linear multisteps schemes to solve the ODE system. The integration is completed with a variable step size, that is controlled by estimating the local truncation error (LTE) at each step. In practice, the step size is adapted in such a way that the estimate of the LTE is smaller than some preset value rtol and atol. 
The default values in the ode method are:

```
ode(rtol = 1e-6, atol = 1e-6)
```

And can be adapted.

However, the actual evaluated LTE is always something above these values. Is there a way to extract this value from the solver?

An example system is given bellow:

```
rm(list = ls())

install.packages('deSolve')
library('deSolve')

# Example ODE system for the Lotka-V predator prey model 
LVmod <- function(Time, State, Pars) {
  with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {
    Ingestion    <- rIng  * Prey * Predator
    GrowthPrey   <- rGrow * Prey * (1 - Prey/K)
    MortPredator <- rMort * Predator

    dPrey        <- GrowthPrey - Ingestion
    dPredator    <- Ingestion * assEff - MortPredator

    return(list(c(dPrey, dPredator)))
  })
}

# values of the parameters
pars  <- c(rIng   = 0.2,    # /day, rate of ingestion
           rGrow  = 1.0,    # /day, growth rate of prey
           rMort  = 0.2 ,   # /day, mortality rate of predator
           assEff = 0.5,    # -, assimilation efficiency
           K      = 10)     # mmol/m3, carrying capacity

#initial values for the predator prey state variables 
yini  <- c(Prey = 1, Predator = 2)

#times at which the ode return state output
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)


# the solver using lsode
out   <- ode(yini, times, LVmod, pars)

summary(out)

str(out)
 deSolve [1:201, 1:3] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "time" "Prey" "Predator"
 - attr(*, "istate")= int [1:21] 2 282 517 NA 1 1 0 52 22 NA ...
 - attr(*, "rstate")= num [1:5] 1 1 201 0 143
 - attr(*, "lengthvar")= int 2
 - attr(*, "type")= chr "lsoda"
```

Comment: don't have the `deSolve` package to test it. can you try `str(out)` and post the structure in the OP as well?

Comment: @chinsoon12, posted